# Object reference not set to an instance of an object Caused by DBNull.Value

Tags: c#, .net, ado.net

```
SqlCommand objsql = new SqlCommand();
.
.
objsql.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Param1", DBNull.Value);
.
.
.
```

I get an exceptional error:

"Object reference not set to an instance of an object"

If i do:

```
objsql.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PaymentMethodID", null);
```

I get the following error:
The parameterized query '(@SupplierQuoteID int,@PaymentMethodID nvarchar(4000),@DueDate d' expects the parameter '@PaymentMethodID', which was not supplied."}

PaymentMethodID is a column in table that takes null.

This error happens in here:

```
string valHolder = null;
valHolder = objSqlCommand.ExecuteScalar().ToString(); 
singleValue = Convert.ToInt32(valHolder);
```

Once objSqlCommand.ExecuteScalar().ToString(); is executed, the error is thrown.
The record gets inserted to the table BUT the ExecuteScalar() doesn't return any
value! It should return the current latest auto-incremented pk, but it doesn't.

NOTE: all errors i have mentioned above are thrown when this line is executed

```
valHolder = objSqlCommand.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
```

Here is the error in full:

```
System.NullReferenceException was caught
  Message="Object reference not set to an instance of an object."
  Source="........"
  StackTrace:
       at ......DAL.ExecuteSQL(SqlCommand sqlCmd, String typeOfExecution) in C:\Users\....\Desktop\........\DAL.cs:line 136
  InnerException:
```

What should i do?

Comment: What is the value of objSqlCommand.ExecuteScalar()?

Comment: What sql statement could have parameter equal to null, can you show me your select statement or something similar?

Comment: As Jeremy (below) and Waleed (above) suggest, it seems your C# is fine, and the problem lies in your SQL.

Comment: I just got your answers, before i read them, here is my code:

<br/><br/>
INSERT INTO SupplierInvoice  ( SupplierQuoteID, PaymentMethodID, DueDate ) VALUES (  @SupplierQuoteID ,  @PaymentMethodID ,  @DueDate  ); <br/><br/>

The code is generated via reflection.

Comment: Problem fixed - here is the correct statement:
INSERT INTO SupplierInvoice ( SupplierQuoteID, PaymentMethodID, DueDate ) VALUES ( @SupplierQuoteID , @PaymentMethodID , @DueDate ); SELECT SuInvoiceID FROM SupplierInvoice WHERE SuInvoiceID = @@IDENTITY

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't call ToString() directly on ExecuteScalar(). Call the objSqlCommand.ExecuteScalar() first, then test to see if that variable is nothing. More than likely that is what is happening.

If you are calling a stored procedure, make sure that `Select SCOPE_IDENTITY()` is the last line of your sproc or the last autonumber will not be returned.

Comment: Fixed. The sql statement had to be:

INSERT INTO SupplierInvoice ( SupplierQuoteID, PaymentMethodID, DueDate ) VALUES ( @SupplierQuoteID , @PaymentMethodID , @DueDate ); SELECT SuInvoiceID FROM SupplierInvoice WHERE SuInvoiceID = @@IDENTITY

Comment: I believe this will work as well and is simpler. INSERT INTO SupplierInvoice ( SupplierQuoteID, PaymentMethodID, DueDate ) VALUES ( @SupplierQuoteID , @PaymentMethodID , @DueDate ); SELECT @@IDENTITY

Comment: Nope. SELECT @@IDENTITY didn't work but SELECT SuInvoiceID FROM SupplierInvoice WHERE SuInvoiceID = @@IDENTITY did.